# VBScript For Each Item in the Array Loop Code

Tags: arrays, foreach, vbscript

So I have this code I put together and gets the job done but what I come to realize is that this can be optimized even more with a For Each Loop and Array. The Code runs an HTA application from the command line and takes two parameters which are already preset. What I want to do and I've been having some issues with is minimizing the amount of code so the only thing I'd have to edit is the array values and keep everything else pretty much static.

Example of what im trying to accomplish (I know the syntax is incorrect just trying to paint a picture):

```
Dim objShell, command
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
command = "cmd /c wmic process where name=""mshta.exe"" call terminate"
objShell.Run command, 0, True 

Dim preMSI
preMSI = "MSI_"

Dim postMSI
postMSI = "_5"

Dim startPKG
startPKG = "Build"

Array(4O, AT, LQ)

ForEach ArrayValue (

 'Prep Name Change
 objShell.run "cmd.exe /C REN D:\"&startPKG&" "&firstArraryValue&"", 0, True
 'Launch and Execute Package Build
 objShell.run "D:\BUILDER.hta """&preMSI+Var1+postMSI&""" ""D:\"&Var1&""" ", 0, True
 objShell.Run command, 0, True 
'Rename the DIR from the first value to the second and so forth as it iterates
 objShell.run "cmd.exe /C REN D:\"&firstArraryValue&" "&secondArraryValue&"", 0, True

)
```

My Actual Code:

```
Dim objShell, command
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
command = "cmd /c wmic process where name=""mshta.exe"" call terminate"
objShell.Run command, 0, True 


Dim preMSI
preMSI = "MSI_"

Dim postMSI
postMSI = "_5"

Dim startPKG
startPKG = "Build"

 Dim Var1
 Var1 = "4O"

 'Prep Name Change
 objShell.run "cmd.exe /C REN D:\"&startPKG&" "&Var1&"", 0, True
 'Launch and Execute Package Build
 objShell.run "D:\BUILDER.hta """&preMSI+Var1+postMSI&""" ""D:\"&Var1&""" ", 0, True
 objShell.Run command, 0, True 

 Dim Var2
 Var2 = "AT"

 'Prep Name Change
 objShell.run "cmd.exe /C REN D:\"&Var1&" "&Var2&"", 0, True
 'Launch and Execute Package Build
 objShell.run "D:\BUILDER.hta """&preMSI+Var2+postMSI&""" ""D:\"&Var2&""" ", 0, True
 objShell.Run command, 0, True 

 Dim Var3
 Var3 = "LQ"

 'Prep Name Change
 objShell.run "cmd.exe /C REN D:\"&Var2&" "&Var3&"", 0, True
 'Launch and Execute Package Build
 objShell.run "D:\BUILDER.hta """&preMSI+Var3+postMSI&""" ""D:\"&Var3&""" ", 0, True
 objShell.Run command, 0, True
```

Comment: You have a map of what you are trying to do, so what's stopping you? I'm struggling to see why you posted the question.

Comment: I know what I need it to, I just don't actually know how to put it together.

Comment: Your "actual code" is not your actual code, there is now way this runs and does anything useful. For example `Var1` is never defined anywhere (`Var1` is not very descriptive, maybe you can think of a better name?)

Comment: @tomalak I deleted it by accident when trying to put together "Example of what im trying to accomplish (I know the syntax is incorrect just trying to paint a picture):" portion of the post

Comment: @Tomalak again this does work but im trying to covert this into an array, foreach loop.

Comment: How can this work when there are variables that are not defined?

Comment: Recheck the code and my previous response!~

Comment: [For Each...Next Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/tywtbxd0%28v%3dvs.84%29). For instance `For Each ArrayValue in Array …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, what you want to do comes close to this (untested, obviously).

I've taken out all the *"start CMD.EXE to rename a folder"* bits, there's much better ways to do this. I've also used VBScript's native interface to WMI.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, FSO, Locator, WMI, process, folder, item

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set WMI = Locator.ConnectServer(".", "ROOT\CIMV2")

' terminate all existing mstha processes
For Each process In WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'mshta.exe'")
    process.terminate
Next

Set folder = FSO.GetFolder("D:\Build")

For Each item In Array("4O", "AT", "LQ")
    folder.Name = item
    Shell.run "D:\BUILDER.hta ""MSI_" & item & "_5"" """ & folder.Path & """", 0, True
Next

folder.Name = "Build"
```

---

If the list `"4O", "AT", "LQ"` is meant to be configurable, pass it as a command line argument when calling the script:

```
cscript /nologo your.vbs "4O,AT,LQ"
```

and in the script

```
For Each item In Split(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0), ",")
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: Looks great I think there is just one missing function, the start directory is "Build" which is renamed to the first array value "Build -> 4O" then for the second pass the directory is renamed again "4O -> AT" with the third pass its done again from the last used value to the newest "AT->LQ" and so forth sometimes there will be anywhere from 5-20 values in the array but they will all use the same files which is why the directory is renamed and recycled. This is an amazing start for me though so thank you

Comment: Since you pass the directory path to the HTA *anyway*, I don't really understand why the directory has to be renamed all the time, that seems rather superfluous to me, but of course I don't know what the HTA does.

Comment: And yeah, my script does the renaming. With every loop iteration, the folder gets a new name.

Comment: Thats awesome as well, I tried running it and got an error for this line -> ```Shell.run "D:\BUILDER.hta ""MSI_" & item & "_5"" """ & folder.Path & """", 0, True``` Path not Found

Comment: Can't help you with that since I have nothing to test with and you did not make any specifications. Meditate over what this line is *supposed* to do and fix it.

Comment: @demo7up The bill is in the post.